# How to load on Snowflake a JSON that has a literal unicode escape char "\\uNo"

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "name": "foo \\uNo bar"
}
```

I'm trying to load this into Snowflake using a STAGE on S3. This is in a CSV file like:

```
{"name": "foo \\uNo bar"}
```

However, when I try to load it, Snowflake breaks with an Error parsing JSON message. If I try to load it directly on Snowflake console, as `SELECT PARSE_JSON('{"name": "foo \\uNo bar"}')`, I get:

> Error parsing JSON: hex digit is expected in \u???? escape sequence, pos 17

The problem is that Snowflake is parsing the string, checking for an unicode digit `\uNo` (which doesn't exist). How can I disable this?

Comment: In the case of your PARSE_JSON call, the issue is that the \\ in your string constant represents just a \ in the actual string, so when PARSE_JSON handles that character sequence it is trying to interpret it as a JSON string escape sequence `\uNo` which is not valid. To properly test PARSE_JSON with this string you would need to use `SELECT PARSE_JSON('{"name": "foo \\\\uNo bar"}');` My guess is that a similar issue is occurring with your CSV (the CSV parser converts `"\\u"` into `"\"` and then the JSON parser interprets it as an escape sequence.

Comment: If you can post an example CSV file and the actual statement you're using to load the CSV data that would help in coming up with a workable solution.

Comment: That's the problem: the string is literally `"foo \uNo bar"`. Converting this to CSV will escape the \, turning this into `"foo \\uNo bar"`, but the `\uNo` is still interpreted by Snowflake as a unicode number, which is wrong in this case. I think I'd need to somehow disable Snowflake interpreting the `\u` on a string, but am not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

The default FILE FORMAT for parsing CSVs in Snowflake is interpreting the double backslash string `'{"name": "foo \\uNo bar"}'` as an escape sequence for the character `\` which means that the character sequence `\uNo` is getting passed to PARSE_JSON which then fails because `\uNo` not a valid escape sequence for a JSON string. You can prevent this by overriding the FILE FORMAT escape sequence settings.

Given this CSV file:

```
JSON
'{"name": "foo \\uNo bar"}'
```

And the following CREATE TABLE and COPY INTO statements:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE JSON_TEST (JSON TEXT);

COPY INTO JSON_TEST
FROM @my_db.public.my_s3_stage/json.csv
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = CSV
               SKIP_HEADER = 1
               FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\''
               ESCAPE = NONE
               ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = NONE);
```

I am able to parse there result as JSON:

```sql
SELECT PARSE_JSON(JSON) FROM JSON_TEST;
```

Which returns

```
+-----------------------------+
| JSON                        |
+-----------------------------|
| { "name": "foo \\uNo bar" } |
+-----------------------------+
```